# Appending image path to the src attribute from database returns src(unknown) Jquery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, jquery-mobile

I am trying to append an image path to the img src attribute but src shows (unknown). The image path is retrieved successfully from Database (I console.logged). I don't know why is not return the path string. Thanks in advance

```
function loadData() {

dbHandler.dataBase.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Properties', [], function (tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length, i;
    var list="";
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        $('#propertiesList').append(`<li>
                    <a  onClick="fullDetails(${ results.rows.item(i).propertyRef})">
                    <img src="${propertyImg(results.rows.item(i).propertyRef)}">
                    <h2><strong>£ ${ results.rows.item(i).monthFee} Pcm </strong></h2>
                    <p>${ flatType (results.rows.item(i).bedQty)} ${ results.rows.item(i).propertyType} to rent in ${ results.rows.item(i).postcode}</p>
                    <p>${ results.rows.item(i).furnitureType}</p>
                    <p>${ results.rows.item(i).notes}</p>
                    <p>Listed on <strong> ${ results.rows.item(i).createdOn} by  ${ results.rows.item(i).postedBy} </strong> </p>
                    <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong><a href=""> Available ${ results.rows.item(i).avalabilityDate}</strong></a></p>
                    </a>
                </li>`).listview('refresh');
    }
    }, null);
 });

function propertyImg(ref){
    var myg="";
        dbHandler.dataBase.transaction(function (tx) {
            tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Propertyimages Where postRef =' + ref , [], function (tx, results) {
                var ded = results.rows.length, i;
                console.log(results)
                var imgss="";
                for (i = 0; i < ded; i++){
                    imgss += `${results.rows.item(i).imgPath}`;      
                }
                myg = imgss
                console.log(myg);
            }, null);
        })
     return myg; 
}
}
```

Comment: Is `executeSql()` asynchronous?

Comment: yes, it is. when I console.log the image path is retrieved successfully but the function is not returning anything

Comment: So you execute the command, return an undefined result, then get the result and log it.  That's the nature of asynchronous methods.

Comment: the problem is that the function is not returning anything therefore src displays unknown. the execution of database works well

Comment: Yes, that's all explained in the linked question.

Comment: Fantastic, thank you very much